# Paul in 1 Timothy 3:16 recognized that Jesus was God manifest in the flesh. Who was the first to realize the same thing?

Tags: john, 1-timothy

Here are a few candidates:

> John 1:14
> The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth.

> John 14:8-9 Philip said, “Lord, show us the Father and that will be enough for us.”
> Jesus answered: “Don’t you know me, Philip, even after I have been among you such a long time? Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’?

> John 1:49 Then Nathaniel declared, "Rabbi, you are the Son of God; you are the king of Israel."

> Matthew 16:16 Simon Peter answered, "You are the Messiah, the Son of the living God."

> Matthew 2:1-2 After Jesus was born in Bethlehem in Judea, during the time of King Herod, Magi a from the east came to Jerusalem and asked, “Where is the one who has been born king of the Jews? We saw his star when it rose and have come to worship him.”

Comment: This question is nearly identical to the one I closed two days ago. Please simply edit that one to bring it on topic rather than creating a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Who first recognized that Jesus was 'God manifest in flesh' [TR] ?

---

Matthew tells us that :

> Now all this was done that it might be fulfilled which was spoken of the Lord by the prophet, saying, *Behold a virgin shall be with child and shall bring forth a son, and they shall call his name Emmanuel, which being interpreted is **God with us .***

> Matthew 1:22,23 from the KJV translated from the Textus Receptus

If 'all this was done' and that which is recorded by the apostle Matthew as done in  fulfillment of the prophecy '... God with us' then it seems to me that Mary and Joseph are the first to recognise that their child, Jesus, is the one spoken of by Isaiah in 7:14 of his prophecy.

This had been spoken 'by (υπο) the Lord, through (δια) the prophet' [EGNT] (1) and now it was fulfilled in the actions of Joseph and Mary.

---

(1) EGNT : The Englishman's Greek New Testament interlinear translation from the Stephens Textus Receptus.